# Nginx is showng welcome-page instead of my Django-app

Tags: django, nginx, gunicorn

Here is /etc/nginx/sites-available/myapp:

```
server{
listen 80;
listen [::]:80;

server_name .somedomain.com;

location = /favicon.ico{access_log off; log_not_found off;}

location /static/ {root /var/www/myapp;}

location / {include proxy_params;
proxy_pass http://unix:/run/gunicorn.sock;}

}
```

Nginx doesn't show my app instead of welcome-page

Also made a simlimk to sites-enabled.

I'm using Django + gunicorn to handle this app, so using ddns and already set my router port preferences.
Gunicorn runs the application normally, but on localhost. Nginx does not want to transfer the application to the domain, although every guide says that it should simply launch it if there are no errors.

I didn't change anything in nginx.conf, so it looks like:

```
user www-data;
worker_processes auto;
pid /run/nginx.pid;
include /etc/nginx/modules-enabled/*.conf;

events {
        worker_connections 768;
        # multi_accept on;
}

http {

        sendfile on;
        tcp_nopush on;
        types_hash_max_size 2048;

        include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
        default_type application/octet-stream;

        ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2 TLSv1.3; # Dropping SSLv3, ref: POODLE
        ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

        access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
        error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

        gzip on;

        include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
        include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
}
```